# nginx behind haproxy to static html ssl getting real IP address

Tags: linux, vue.js, nginx, haproxy

My problem is getting the "real" IP address from the web at nginx level serving a static vuejs site via ssl.

I want to block certain IP addresses, how can I get the real IP address if I can't use proxy pass, since I only link to a static location?

haproxy (tcp) (port: 443) ==> encrypted request ==> nginx (port: 8085) request pass to ==> '/' location getting real IP for range blocking.

Please also see questions/comments in the nginx vhost file. Am I on the right track here or does this need to be done entirely differently?

haproxy setup:

```
frontend ssl_front_433 xx.xx.xx.xx:443
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    use_backend ssl_nginx_backend_8085

backend ssl_nginx_backend_8085
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option  tcp-check
    server  srv-2 127.0.0.1:8085  check  fall 3 rise 2 inter 4s
```

nginx setup:

```
server {
   listen 8085 ssl;
   server_name mydomain;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   ssl_certificate      ./fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key  ./privkey.pem;
   include include.d/ssl.conf;

   // I want to only allow certain ip addresses
   // haproxy of course always returns 127.0.0.1 thus this is not working 
   include include.d/ip_range.conf;  

   location / {
        //how to get the proxy headers to be applied here?
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        // do I need a proxy pass and if so where should I pass to,
        // in order to use it with static html/js?
        // can I use an upstream to a static location?
        //proxy_pass http://;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score -1):

On the nginx side you can control which IP addresses or ranges are permitted with a `deny all` and an `allow` range to your server block like so:

```
allow  192.168.1.0/24;
deny   all;
```

Note: The nginx docs are always an excellent place to start, here's the docs for [restricting access by IP addresses](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/#restrict) and ranges.

First, I would challenge you to reconsider why you need a load balancer with haproxy for something as simple as a html/css/js static site.  More infrastructure introduces more complications.

Second, the upstream in nginx is only needed if you want to point requests to a local wsgi server for example, in your case this is static content so you shouldn't need to point to an upstream – not unless you have some sort of wsgi service you want to forward requests to.

Finally, as for haproxy only forwarding requests as 127.0.0.1, first make sure the IP is in the header (i.e. `X-Real-IP`) then you can try to add something like this to your haproxy config ([source](https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2019/06/04/real-client-ip-address-nginx-behind-haproxy-reverse-proxy/)), if you indeed want to keep haproxy:

```
frontend all_https
  option forwardfor header X-Real-IP
  http-request set-header X-Real-IP %[src]
```

The haproxy documentation is also a good resource for [preserving source IP addresses](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/preserve-source-ip-address-despite-reverse-proxies/).

Comment: the allow and deny is done in my include ip_range and as nothing to do with the problem. In order to deny and allow I need the real IP address. haproxy does not touch http headers because it handles the request in encrypted form and passes it on to nginx. nginx then unpacks it and reads the headers. At this point all request come in at 127.0.0.1 from haproxy. Therefore I need nginx to scrape these headers out and tell me the real IP and weather it is allowed or not.

Comment: On your "second" point, upstream is used for all sorts of backend services/sockets not just wsgi.

Comment: Have you verified the IP addresses are in the headers?  If you're using something like PHP on the front end you might need to enable that in the config, for instance.  Anyway, the allow and deny will still be useful once you ensure your headers are indeed present, its not going to be irrelevant to your solution.  The upstream thing is a red herring and has nothing to do with IP forwarding, a wsgi scenario was just a "for example" use case, but even with a socket that's being used for another service which you don't have, nor need, with a static site.